# Looking up values from one csv-file in another csv-file, using a third csv-file as map

Tags: python, r, csv, numpy, pandas

I didn't quite figure how to formulate this question, suggestions to improve the title is welcome.

I have three files: *e_data.csv*, *t_data.csv* and *e2d.csv*. I want to merge `e_id`, `t_id`, `gene_name` and `value` into one file, as represented by *desired_result.csv*. The naive approach is as follows:

1. For each row in *e_data.csv*, extract `e_id` and `value`.
2. Check *e2t.csv* for which `t_id` that corresponds to the given `e_id`.
3. Check *t_data.csv* for which `gene_name` that corresponds to the given `t_id`.
4. Merge them all to one file.

Please see the following example for what I'm trying to achieve:

*e_data.csv:*

```
   e_id  value
     1    110
     2    240
     3    370
```

*e2t.csv:*

```
   e_id  t_id
     1    10
     2    24
     3    32
```

*t_data.csv:*

```
  t_id gene_name
   10     Gene1
   24     Gene2
   32     Gene3
```

*desired_result.csv:*

```
  gene_name t_id e_id value
     Gene1   10    1   110
     Gene2   24    2   240
     Gene3   32    3   370
```

There's no limitation to which tools or language to use, but I would prefer to use Python, as that's what I'm most familiar with. R could also be an option. I've already implemented a solution in pure Python, but the datasets are rather large, and I'm hoping something like Pandas or Numpy can speed things up a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you load all the csvs using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) you can just iteratively [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) them so long as the column names are consistent:

```
In [149]:
merged = t_data.merge(e2t.merge(e_data))
merged

Out[149]:
   t_id gene_name  e_id  value
0    10     Gene1     1    110
1    24     Gene2     2    240
2    32     Gene3     3    370
```

The above works as by default it will try to merge on matching column names and perform an inner merge so the column values must match on lhs and rhs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I get an empty DataFrame when trying to do t_data.merge(e2t.merge(e_data)). But the column names are the same as in your answer. Merging e2t and e_data works, however. I'll look into the documentation on merge, perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'd look at the output of each merge, also you don't necessarily need to merge the entire df to debug this, ie. `e2t.iloc[:5].merge(e_data.iloc[:5])` will merge just the first 5 lines

Comment: For some reason, e2t and t_data won't merge in my example, which is identical to the data in the question. I shouldn't matter that the the position of the t_id column is different in the two files, right? On my real data it works, however, and I have to say, it is lightning fast compared to my pure python solution.

Comment: position doesn't care, I'd check the column names to see if the spelling is identical `e2t.columns.tolist()` and `t_date.columns.tolist()`

Comment: Do all the entries in the DataFrames have to be the same data type? If I'm changing "Gene1" etc to integers (or, conversely, the IDs to strings), the merge goes fine.

Comment: Not sure, I'd imagine it will either barf or produce a mixed dtype column

Comment: OK, I just tried this, the dtypes have to match otherwise you get an empty df, so that's your problem